# how to use a ssh tunnel to proxy a database

Tags: ssh

I have a cloud sql instance running a postgresql database. This database is behind a firewall with no access to internet. I want to ease the developers pain to connect to database.

I thought I can use ssh to create a tunnel in the bastian host to proxy the connections to the could sql database, but I cannot find proper way of doing this. This was developers can connect to bastian host and browse the database.

But setting this proved to be more difficult than what I thought to be. Various option, but each one of them come a little short of what I want to do.

Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Comment: The "bastion" is supposed to allow monitored, controlled ssh access. I believe you are trying to achieve something that the ops of your company designed their infrastructure against. You should really get support from them. Additionally, there is another concern: you are probably going to give your developers access to the SQL database via your personal identity (over SSH). They might then inherit permissions they are not supposed to. And should any of them do anything harmful, wilfully or not, you will most probably take the blame.

Comment: What did you try? Seems simple enough to me for each developer to ssh to the bastion establishing a local forward of 5432 and/or 5433 and then they can access via localhost:5432 or localhost:5433. If still no connection, then you have to allow those ports through the firewall.